# HTTP Connection between Grafana and Nginx with Docker

Tags: http, nginx, docker-compose, grafana

I'm pretty new to the area so please bear with me ^^°

I have two docker containers (Grafana and Nginx) which I created via docker compose.

```
services:
  rainviewer:
    image: nginx
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./rainviewer/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro


  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    user: "0:0"
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      GF_PANELS_DISABLE_SANITIZE_HTML: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
```

In Grafana I want to display an HTML page from Nginx. But I don't want to have to specify the IP but only the name of the Docker container.

Both containers are located in the same network. I was able to check this with a ping and in principle I do the same with the Influxdb and it works. However, when I try to display the HTML page via Grafana, I cannot access the page. This only works if I enter the IP address of the host computer.

**This works**
[image: Works]

**This doesn't works**
[image: Dont Work]

Can you help me here?

I have already done some googling here and tried to make a few configurations in Nginx for the forwarding. Unfortunately so far without success as I don't really understand the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

- Use `src="http://localhost:8081"` in grafana's text component.
- Override nginx config, it looks like you use default configs, we'll only touch one of them. Put below as `default.conf` to the directory where docker-compose.yml is.
- Restart apps (`docker compose down && docker rm $(docker ps -aq) && docker compose up`, this is the most reliable one I remember)

```
server {
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

[image: X]

### How it works

The problem comes from `iframe`, nginx does not allow its site to "show" in an iframe, thus you need to allow it. Browsers respects these values. That's why in earlier we could get from `curl`, also your nginx site is probably works from `localhost:8081` (default nginx image does). Also another misleading thins is, actually browser makes request to the iframe, thus `http://localhost:8081` is the correct url, you can check this from network tab in developer tools.

`X-Frame-Options` is the header browsers check if the frontend server allows their content to be inside an `<iframe>`, we say only allow if they're in same origin (`localhost`) thus we add this config to nginx.

A little tip if you continue to develop this architecture, , if you add another `add_header` in a "child" block, parents' `add_header`s are not inherited. For example, if you want to add a cache option like `Cache-Control: no-cache` for only to the `location /`, `add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";` is completely overriden, you need to repeat that. This behaviour waste my time, hopefully not yours :)

Comment: This is one of the things  i've already tried. Sadly without success.

Comment: Can you try following command: `docker exec grafana 'curl http://rainviewer:80/'` does it gives you html?

Comment: That's interesting.
'curl http://rainviewer:80/' inside the Grafana container gives me correct HTML code. If I use the same address inside the Text panel of Grafana I don't get this HTMP page.

Comment: Updated the answer, apparently it's from `iframe`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)
Unfortunately, that doesn't work yet either.
Yes: I only use the standard configuration and have not changed anything here. I have added your change (X-Frame-Options) to the default.conf. And I am now also using the localhost:8081 in the Grafana panel.
Unfortunately this does not work either...

Did I miss something?

Comment: I found the problem on my end...
My Docker runs on a different host and I access it from my local machine.
Apparently Grafana (or Firefox?) takes the localhost from the local computer and of course cannot see anything there because there is nothing on my local computer.
I have now run the whole thing locally on my computer. That works.
Many thanks for your help and your time :)